# converting .properties file string into integer in java

Tags: java

I cant convert my codes String value to Integer, how to do it. 
I saved some values in my properties file and want to store from that file,
but after storing the String I cannot convert it to Integer.
Is there any better way.

Thanks in advance,

```
package com.mkyong.properties;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Getfromresources {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;

try {

    input = new FileInputStream("D://config.properties");
int x=0;
    // load a properties file
    prop.load(input);
    // get the property value and print it out
    String s1=prop.getProperty("value");
            String s2;
            s2=s1;
            x=Integer.parseInt(s2);
            System.out.println(x);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
}
```

`

This is the stack trace I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 3" 
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) 
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569) 
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) 
at com.mkyong.properties.Getfromresources.main(Getfromresources.java:24) 
C:\Users\tamimwasif\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: 
Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Whats the error you're getting?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 3"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at com.mkyong.properties.Getfromresources.main(Getfromresources.java:24)
C:\Users\tamimwasif\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Integer.parseInt is the normal way to go. Are you sure there is no space and no other character around the number in the file ?

Comment: Well you have a space before `3` in " 3".

Comment: #Tue Jun 19 09:11:29 BDT 2018
value=\ 3
#Tue Jun 19 09:12:20 BDT 2018
tablenames0=x1
#Tue Jun 19 09:12:23 BDT 2018
tablenames1=x11
#Tue Jun 19 09:12:26 BDT 2018
tablenames2=x111
#Tue Jun 19 09:12:27 BDT 2018
value=\ 3
#Tue Jun 19 09:13:09 BDT 2018
tablenames0=tt
#Tue Jun 19 09:13:12 BDT 2018
tablenames1=tt1
#Tue Jun 19 09:13:16 BDT 2018
tablenames2=tt11
#Tue Jun 19 09:13:17 BDT 2018
value=\ 3

Comment: yess hava a space

Comment: So before you actually try to convert it call/use `s2.trim()`